# How is a Sparse RBM different from a Gaussian-Bernoulli RBM

Tags: machine-learning, restricted-boltzmann-machine

[Sparse RBM are described in this paper](http://cs.stanford.edu/people/ang/papers/nips07-sparsedeepbeliefnetworkv2.pdf)

Gaussian-Bernoulli RBMs are describe (kinda poorly) in [this paper](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/3048-greedy-layer-wise-training-of-deep-networks.pdf) as Gaussian Units,
and more clearly in this [masters thesis.](http://www.ini.rub.de/data/documents/tns/masterthesis_janmelchior.pdf)

Sparse RBM: (Quoting direct from the [paper](http://cs.stanford.edu/people/ang/papers/nips07-sparsedeepbeliefnetworkv2.pdf), Page 3)
$$P(v_{i}|\mathbf{h})=\mathcal{N}(c_{i}+\sum_{j}w_{ij}h_{j},\,\sigma^{2})$$
$$P(h_{j}|\mathbf{v})=logistic\left(\frac{1}{\sigma^{2}}(b_{j}+\sum_{i}w_{ij}v_{i}\right)$$

Gaussian-Bernoulli RBMs (Quoting less directly from the [masters thesis.](http://www.ini.rub.de/data/documents/tns/masterthesis_janmelchior.pdf), pages 38  and 36. Some substitutions/expansions made)
$$v_{i}|\mathbf{h}\sim\mathcal{N}(c_{i}+\sum_{j}w_{ij}h_{i},\,\sigma_{i}^{2})$$
$$P(h_{j}=1|\mathbf{v})=logistic\left(b_{j}+\sum_{i}w_{ij}\frac{v_{i}}{\sigma_{i}^{2}}\right)$$

So the difference would be a scaling factor of $\frac{1}{\sigma}$ on $b_i$. and $b_i$ is a learned factor controlling the threshold, so will learn away a scaling factor.

They seem to have the same PDFs, though to formulation of the energy function is superficially different, I think it simplifies to be the same.

I the difference is $\sigma$ in a sparse RBM is a  definable parameter -- that controls sparseness.
But $\sigma_i$ in a Gaussian-Bernoulli  is the variance of the the features $i$.

They are both trained the same way with Contrastive Divergence.

is this right?
are there more connections between them?
Have i got it all wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The models in both papers are Gaussian-Bernoulli RBMs. The difference is the sparse variant includes a term in the object which penalizes hidden units whose conditional expectation deviates from a fixed constant, $p$. See equation (4) in section 3.1 of the sparse RBM paper you link.